# How to recover my properties with PortPHP Bundle in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony

**(Sorry for my english)**

I am a beginner with Symfony and I have a little problem in one of my functions.

I want to import data from an Excel or CSV file via a file input Symfony formType.

I haven't an error message. everything is working properly. I can send the dates but I do not know how to send the other data like First name, last name…

In this function, I use the [PortPHP](https://portphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) bundle.

/* -------- My entity -------- */

```
    namespace App\Entity;
    use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CollaboratorRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity(
     *     fields={"emailAddress"},
     *     message="Un collaborateur avec cette adresse email existe déja."
     *     )
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @Vich\Uploadable()
     */
    class Collaborator
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $firstName;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $lastName;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
         * @Assert\Email(
         *      message = "L'adresse email {{ value }} n'est pas valide",
         * )
         */
        private $emailAddress;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $phone;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $cellphone;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         * @Assert\DateTime()
         */
        private $birthday;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         * @Assert\DateTime()
         */
        private $arrivalDate;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $titleJob;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Agency", inversedBy="collaborators")
         */
        private $agency;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Department", inversedBy="collaborators")
         */
        private $department;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         *
         */
        private $slug;

        /**
         * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
         *
         * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="collaborator", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
         *
         * @var File
         */
        private $imageFile;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         *
         * @var string
         */
        private $imageName;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
         *
         * @var integer
         */
        private $imageSize;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         * @ORM\OrderBy({"fullName": "ASC"})
         *
         * @var \DateTime
         */
        private $updatedAt;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", mappedBy="speaker")
         */
        private $events;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->events = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Check before and after persistence in database
         * @ORM\PrePersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function initializeSlug()
        {
            if (empty($this->slug)) {
                $slugify = new Slugify();
                $this->slug = $slugify->slugify($this->firstName . '-' . $this->lastName);
            }
        }

        public function getFullName()
        {
            return $this->firstName . ' ' . $this->getLastName();
        }

        public function getLastName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->lastName;
        }

        public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
        {
            $this->lastName = $lastName;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getFirstName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->firstName;
        }

        public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
        {
            $this->firstName = $firstName;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getEmailAddress(): ?string
        {
            return $this->emailAddress;
        }

        public function setEmailAddress(string $emailAddress): self
        {
            $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getPhone(): ?string
        {
            return $this->phone;
        }

        public function setPhone(string $phone): self
        {
            $this->phone = $phone;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getCellphone(): ?string
        {
            return $this->cellphone;
        }

        public function setCellphone(string $cellphone): self
        {
            $this->cellphone = $cellphone;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getBirthday(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->birthday;
        }

        public function setBirthday(\DateTimeInterface $birthday): self
        {
            $this->birthday = $birthday;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getArrivalDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->arrivalDate;
        }

        public function setArrivalDate(\DateTimeInterface $arrivalDate): self
        {
            $this->arrivalDate = $arrivalDate;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getTitleJob(): ?string
        {
            return $this->titleJob;
        }

        public function setTitleJob(string $titleJob): self
        {
            $this->titleJob = $titleJob;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getAgency(): ?Agency
        {
            return $this->agency;
        }

        public function setAgency(?Agency $agency): self
        {
            $this->agency = $agency;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getDepartment(): ?Department
        {
            return $this->department;
        }

        public function setDepartment(?Department $department): self
        {
            $this->department = $department;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getSlug(): ?string
        {
            return $this->slug;
        }

        public function setSlug(string $slug): self
        {
            $this->slug = $slug;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getImageFile(): ?File
        {
            return $this->imageFile;
        }

        /**
         * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
         * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
         * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
         * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
         * during Doctrine hydration.
         *
         * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $imageFile
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
        {
            $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

            if (null !== $imageFile) {
                // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
                // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
                $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
            }
        }

        public function getImageName(): ?string
        {
            return $this->imageName;
        }

        public function setImageName(?string $imageName): void
        {
            $this->imageName = $imageName;
        }

        public function getImageSize(): ?int
        {
            return $this->imageSize;
        }

        public function setImageSize(?int $imageSize): void
        {
            $this->imageSize = $imageSize;
        }

        /**
         * @return Collection|Event[]
         */
        public function getEvents(): Collection
        {
            return $this->events;
        }

        public function addEvent(Event $event): self
        {
            if (!$this->events->contains($event)) {
                $this->events[] = $event;
                $event->addSpeaker($this);
            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function removeEvent(Event $event): self
        {
            if ($this->events->contains($event)) {
                $this->events->removeElement($event);
                $event->removeSpeaker($this);
            }

            return $this;
        }

    }
```

/* ------ My controller ------ */

````
     * @Route("/collaborators", name="collaborator_index")
     * @param CollaboratorRepository $collaboratorRepository
     * @param Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Ddeboer\DataImport\Exception
     */
    public function collaborator(
        CollaboratorRepository $collaboratorRepository,
        Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs,
        Request $request
    ): Response
    {
        // Add the breadcrumbs after the home
        $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem("Liste des collaborateurs", "collaborator_index");
        // Add the home breadcrumbs
        $breadcrumbs->prependRouteItem("Dashboard", "dashboard_index");

        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $upload = new Import();

        $form = $this->createForm(ImportType::class, $upload);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $file = new \SplFileObject('./../public/storage/import.csv');
            $csvReader = new CsvReader($file);

            $csvReader->setHeaderRowNumber(0);

            /** @var TYPE_NAME $csvReader */
            $workflow = new StepAggregator($csvReader);

            $doctrineWriter = new DoctrineWriter($manager, 'App\Entity\Collaborator');
            $workflow->addWriter($doctrineWriter);


            // Add a converter to the workflow that will convert `birthday` and `arrivalDate`
            $dateTimeConverter = new DateTimeValueConverter('d/m/Y');
            $converterStep = new ValueConverterStep();
            $converterStep
                ->add('birthday', $dateTimeConverter)
                ->add('arrivalDate', $dateTimeConverter);
            $workflow->addStep($converterStep);

            //Process the workflow
            $workflow->process();

        }

        return $this->render('admin/collaborator/collaborator.html.twig', [
            'collaborators' => $collaboratorRepository->findAll(),
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }```
````

/* ------ My formType ------ */

```
namespace App\Form;
use App\Entity\Import;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

class ImportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'file',
                VichFileType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Fichier CSV',
                    'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Choisissez votre fichier'
                    ]
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Import::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

/* ------ My twig template ------ */

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des collaborateurs{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <div class="padding">
        {{ wo_render_breadcrumbs() }}
        <h2 class="mb-4">Liste des collaborateurs</h2>
        {% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ label }} fade show align-items-center" role="alert">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle alert-icon mr-3"></i>
                {% for message in messages %}
                    {{ message | striptags }}
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="d-inline-block">
                    <div class="my-2 dropdown">
                        <button type="button"
                                id="dropdownMenuButton"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                                class="btn w-sm btn-primary mr-2 dropdown-toggle"
                                data-placement="right"
                        >
                            Ajouter
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('collaborator_create') }}">Ajouter</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Importer</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                         aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Importer par fichier</h3>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                {{ form_start(form) }}
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div>
                                                <p>Utilisez le formulaire ci-dessous pour importer les données des
                                                    collaborateurs depuis le fichier CSV<br/>
                                                    <span class="small font-italic">Les données doivent être séparées par un point virgule (;)</span>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="custom-file">
                                                {{ form_row(form.file) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Importer</button>
                                </div>
                                {{ form_end(form) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-block float-right">
                    <div class="my-2">
                        <a href="{{ path('export_index') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Exporter</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-theme v-middle display responsive nowrap" id="collaboratorTable"
                   style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Téléphone</th>
                    <th>Poste</th>
                    <th>Agence</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for collaborator in collaborators %}
                    <tr class="" data-id="{{ collaborator.id }}">
                        <td>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ collaborator.id }}</small>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="item-amount text-sm">
                                {% if collaborator.imageName is not null %}
                                    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(collaborator, 'imageFile') }}"
                                         class="rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="height: 25px"/>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="{{ asset('images/collaborators/user-unknown.jpg') }}"
                                         class="rounded-circle mr-2" alt="" style="height: 25px"/>
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ collaborator.fullName }}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.emailAddress }}</span></td>
                        <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.phone }}</span></td>
                        <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.titleJob }}</span></td>
                        <td><span class="item-amount text-sm">{{ collaborator.agency }}</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="item-action dropdown text-right">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="text-muted"><i
                                            class="i-con i-con-more"><i></i></i></a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right bg-dark" role="menu">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="{{ path('collaborator_show', {'slug': collaborator.slug}) }}">Consulter </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="{{ path('collaborator_edit', {'id': collaborator.id}) }}">Modifier</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    {{ include('admin/partials/_delete_form.html.twig', {routeName: 'collaborator_delete', entityId: collaborator.id}, with_context = false) }} {# Import the delete confirmation modal JavaScript #}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            {# Import the custom JavaScript here #}
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have any error output? What isn't working correctly?

Comment: I haven't an error message. everything is working properly. I can send the dates but I do not know how to send the other data (First name, last name ...).

Comment: I would edit your question to add some additional information such as that. To me, it wasn't clear what you were struggling to get working from your question. You might check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need additional help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I make the changes right away :)